# Javascript set default session path

Tags: javascript, session, caching, cookies, session-cookies

I have a webhost which don't allow sessions unless you define the path, for php I simply added ini_set('session.save_path',getcwd(). '/../tmp');

but I also use cookies/sessions for javascript and they dont save, I was wondering if it's possible to define a default for the sessions to be stored in the same folder

thanks

Comment: which javascript web server software are you running?

Comment: Can we see your code for the Javascript that sets the cookie?

Comment: its run on nginx and heres a the code which adds table[0][id] = 0;